# For loop vary one parameter keeping the other constant

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a for loop in which I only want to vary one parameter `p` while keeping the other `q` constant. `p` and `q` are "auto regression" and "moving average" orders in `gls()`. How to achieve that? Here is my code (not working):

```
cor.results <- NULL
for(p in 0:3) {
  cor.temp <- gls(di.posaf~di.index + factor(subject):day + factor(subject), data=PMBCall2, method='ML', correlation=corARMA(p=p, q=0, form = ~ day | subject)) #I want to vary p only and keep q constant
  cor.results <- rbind(cor.results, c(p, q, logLik(cor.temp), AIC(cor.temp))) 
}
```

Comment: 1) I don't think your inputs for `corARMA` function are correct. It takes **4** compulsory arguments. See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-145/topics/corARMA). 2) Your `q` is already fixed as 0. 3) `c(p, q, logLik(cor.temp), AIC(cor.temp))` should probably be `c(p, 0, logLik(cor.temp), AIC(cor.temp))`. 4) It is very difficult to give further assistance if you do not share a piece of your data using `dput(head(PMBCall2, N))`; `N` should be large enough for a representative sample.

Comment: Thank you @ekoam. I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `corARMA()` does not accept `p`=0 & `q`=0 at the same time and so I increased the starting value of `p` to 1

```
cor.results <- NULL
for(p in 1:3) {
  cor.temp <- gls(di.posaf~di.index + factor(subject):day + factor(subject), data=PMBCall2, method='ML', correlation=corARMA(p=p, q=0, form = ~ day | subject)) #p should start from 1
  cor.results <- rbind(cor.results, c(p, q, logLik(cor.temp), AIC(cor.temp))) 
}
```